# Can we use "is" instead "was"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> A: Who was the man we saw with Anna yesterday.
>
> B: He **was** her brother.

Is the above "he was her brother" grammatically correct? can we use "is" instead "was"? because it is fact that he is her brother. and still he is.

Comment: You said "he *is* still" her brother, so why change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would usually say "Who was the man..." when referring to a particular incident in the past "that we saw with Anna yesterday." I might use "Who is the man..." is the question was more general - "Who's the man Anna is always with on her lunch break?"

In either case, I think responding with "He is" is okay. The reason why "He is sounds okay as a response to "Who was" is because while the asker is talking about a past event (seeing the man yesterday), the answer-er is talking about a current truth - the man yesterday IS Anna's brother. that did not change since yesterday.

In in the first case, for the same reason I would not use "He was" (because that indicates he has somehow ceased to be her brother), but you could say "That was her brother." I'm not 100% sure how to explain it to you, but "That was" sounds perfectly correct to me - perhaps because it sounds like it's referring to the event (seeing him), so it's okay to use past tense.